# how to call a asynchronous function in the html for angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm calling a function df(stuff, morestuff) that returns data from firebase in the html. But the function ends up returning no data because df it is an async function.  WHAT TO DO??

```
<div>{{ df(stuff, morestuff) }}</div>


$scope.df = function(stuff, morestuff){
    ref.child(stuff).child(morestuff).once('value', function(dataSnap){
        return dataSnap.val();
    })
}
```

Help is much appreciated here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return data that hasn't been loaded yet. The solution is to instead rephrase your code into "when the data has loaded, do...".

```
function(stuff, morestuff){
    ref.child(stuff).child(morestuff).once('value', $timeout(function(dataSnap){
        $scope.df = dataSnap.val();
    }));
}
```

This has the advantage that it will even work when you use `on()` (instead of `once()`) and will in that case automatically update the AngularJS views when the data gets updated.

Comment: Thanks Frank.  I've used that technique before, but im calling that function multiple times inside a nested ng-repeat.  i could do a scope object and fill in the values, I was just hoping there was to get a return value from the function.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible. It's loaded asynchronously and the browser cannot (and should not) wait for the data to come back.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple, you make a binding, of some variable, and in controller fill this variable with what ever you want.

HTML:

```
<div>{{variable}}</div>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    ref.child(stuff).child(morestuff).once('value', function(dataSnap){
        $scope.variable = dataSnap
        //  Verify if angular isn't digesting already (procesing changes)
        if(!$scope.$$phase) {
            //  Angular ain't aware of changes, so we make it do it's cycle.
            $scope.$apply()
        }
    })
}])
```

Comment: Thanks Akxe, please see above comment to Frank.